# Date related operations in jinja2

Tags: date, jinja2, email-templates, cratejoy

I am using [cratejoy](https://www.cratejoy.com/) to create a 'subscription boxes' based website.It used jinja2 as its templating engine.
Now I am editing email templates where I want to access order items and send my customized messages.

My question is how to do date related operations using jinja2 syntax just as getting-

date on next monday,
next month name,
first monday of next month etc

I am able to do everything easiliy with javascript but it wont be helpful since email clients wont run JS.

Any help will be appreciated !!

Comment: its better do these things in python then pass it to your template

Comment: Thanks @SumanKalyan, but I dont have access to server side